# Как определить находится ли страница в кросс-доменных ифреймах?

Tags: javascript, iframe, безопасность, cross-domain

'Mysite.com' находится в ифрейме у liveweave.com, а он в свою очередь у codepen.io
Пример: http://codepen.io/rd2d2/pen/qbawxW
 
Как из 'Mysite.com' определить, находится ли он в нескольких кросс-доменных ифреймах?

```
<iframe src='http://mysite.com/' width='100%' height='300'></iframe>
<!-- Как средствами JS определить более 2х кросс-доменных ифрейма? -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У каждого фрейма есть своя переменная `window`. Чтобы получить эту переменную для родительского окна можно воспользоваться свойством `window.parent`.

Однако в вашей задаче есть проблема. Из-за ограничений [same-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) в достаточно современных браузерах нет возможности узнать адрес "не своего" родительского фрейма (свойство `location.href` в режиме доступа "только запись"). Поэтому можно попробовать читать свойство `location.href` у родительского фрейма. Если будет исключение - значит родительский фрейм - "чужой".

Соответсвенно ваша проверка может выглядеть так:

```
var countAlienDomains, frameParent, frameHref;
countAlienDomains = 0;
frameParent = window;
while (frameParent != frameParent.parent) {
    frameParent = frameParent.parent;
    try {
        frameHref = frameParent.location.href;
    } catch (e) {
        countAlienDomains += 1;
    }
}
console.log(countAlienDomains);
```

Comment: Спасибо, но похоже что `window.document.location` не доступно - Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin...
Может есть другой вариант получить количество ифреймов?

Comment: `while (window.self != window.top)` - похоже на бесконечный цикл.

Comment: @rd2d2 Извиняюсь. Поспешил - глупость написал. Переделал и проверил.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Всё работает.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте, может поможет:

```
top.module.something1('hello');
```

или с Jquery https://stackoverflow.com/a/2945106:

```
var frameDocument = $('frame[name="mainFrame"]', top.document)[0].contentDocument;
$(frameDocument).find('body').prepend('<h1>TEST!!!!</h1>')
```